# Why does Ember Data think save() is failing when it’s not?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I have an Ember model I am saving to a database. When I call

```
model.save().then(function () {
  alert('Everything worked.');
}, function () {
  alert('Save failed.');
});
```

the record persists to the database, the network request to the API call that does the saving responds with a status code of 200 and a body of

```
{
  "id": 11,
  "send_date": "2014-12-01T23:20:31.821Z",
  "expiration_date": "2014-12-08T06:00:00.000Z",
  "message": "What is happening here",
  "url": null,
  "feature_id": null
}
```

and no errors appear in the console. Everything works perfectly, *except* that the rejection handler `alert('Save failed.')` is called every time. The success handler is never called. Why?

---

**EDIT**

The `reason` passed to the fail handler is this error:

```
column: 22
line: 11256
message: "undefined is not an object (evaluating 'factory.typeKey')"
sourceURL: "http://localhost:8080/bower_components/ember-data/ember-data.js"
stack: "modelFor@http://localhost:8080/bower_components/ember-data/ember-data.js:11256:22
        recordForId@http://localhost:8080/bower_components/ember-data/ember-data.js:10727:33
        deserializeRecordId@http://localhost:8080/bower_components/ember-data/ember-data.js:11692:38
        http://localhost:8080/bower_components/ember-data/ember-data.js:11670:30
        http://localhost:8080/bower_components/ember-data/ember-data.js:9456:24
        http://localhost:8080/bower_components/ember-data/ember-data.js:5295:37
        http://localhost:8080/bower_components/ember/ember.js:14899:24
        forEach@http://localhost:8080/bower_components/ember/ember.js:14741:18
        forEach@http://localhost:8080/bower_components/ember/ember.js:14897:21
        mapForEach@http://localhost:8080/bower_components/ember-data/ember-data.js:5302:29
        eachRelationship@http://localhost:8080/bower_components/ember-data/ember-data.js:9455:49
        normalizeRelationships@http://localhost:8080/bower_components/ember-data/ember-data.js:11666:28
        didSaveRecord@http://localhost:8080/bower_components/ember-data/ember-data.js:11125:40
        http://localhost:8080/bower_components/ember-data/ember-data.js:11905:28
        tryCatch@http://localhost:8080/bower_components/ember/ember.js:45817:24
        invokeCallback@http://localhost:8080/bower_components/ember/ember.js:45829:25
        publish@http://localhost:8080/bower_components/ember/ember.js:45800:25
        http://localhost:8080/bower_components/ember/ember.js:29071:17
        invoke@http://localhost:8080/bower_components/ember/ember.js:634:22
        flush@http://localhost:8080/bower_components/ember/ember.js:684:21
        end@http://localhost:8080/bower_components/ember/ember.js:147:32
        run@http://localhost:8080/bower_components/ember/ember.js:202:23
        apply@http://localhost:8080/bower_components/ember/ember.js:18384:31
        run@http://localhost:8080/bower_components/ember/ember.js:17001:19
        success@http://localhost:8080/bower_components/ember-data/ember-data.js:1879:24
        fire@http://localhost:8080/bower_components/jquery/jquery.js:2913:35
        fireWith@http://localhost:8080/bower_components/jquery/jquery.js:3025:11
        done@http://localhost:8080/bower_components/jquery/jquery.js:7400:25
        http://localhost:8080/bower_components/jquery/jquery.js:7822:17"
```

---

**EDIT**

I fixed the error for now by removing a `belongsTo` relationship from the Ember Data model. The relationship was for a feature that I was going to implement later, so I'm removing it for now. Guess I will cross that bridge when I get to it.

Comment: Could you try this: `}, function(reason) alert(reason); });` ?

Comment: Does the JSON response need to be namespaced with the model type?

Comment: If you turn on "Pause on Caught Exceptions" in devtools you are likely to be able to see the problem *in flagrante delicto*.